# What's the best approch to Covert Paradox(objectpal) system in to .Net?

Tags: .net, wpf, paradox

We have old system in paradox and db is sqlserver 2000. We need to convert paradox(objectpal) system in to .net WPF. We create architecture in .net but any type of automation tool avilable so we can convert code of paradox into c#  code ?

or what's the best way to do that from object pal to c#?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find anthing to convert ObjectPal to C# or anything else. It may also have been using the Borland Database Engine (BDE) to for the access routines.
That database may be easy to convert even if you have to do it manually.

But, with all that work to do, you may want to look at a serious review of the tables and your data. Then look at what each feature does and just recode it entirely.

You can take a look at Embarcadero Technologies, which is the current owner of the Paradox technologies. They have some .Net stuff, database utilities, etc. You may find something that can help there.

Comment: they use sqlserver 2000 as database so it's not big issue to migrate it to sqlserver 2008 but issue is how we migrate from objectPal to c#, What's the best way we can convert code of objectPal?

Answer (score 0):

It's a full rewrite, unfortunately. ObjectPAL lets you attach code to almost any object on screen, from fields to the whole form. So there is no "single" piece of ObjectPAL you can convert.